# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component and states are not getting updated

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this warning message and my states are also not getting updated. Could someone please help me in this:

here is the code:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    const { state } = this.props.location;
    console.log(state);
    if (state && state.mesg) {
      this.setState({
        mesg: this.props.location.state.mesg,
        mesgType: this.props.location.state.mesgType
      });
      const stateCopy = { ...state };
      delete stateCopy.mesg;
      this.props.history.replace({ state: stateCopy });
    }

    this.closeMesg(1000);

    let pageNo = this.props.location.search.split("=");
    await this.fetchProfessionsAPI(pageNo[1] || 1);
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  };
```

now this mesg and mesgType is not getting updated . Also , the following error is coming:

> index.js:1472 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak
>   in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous
>   tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
>       in Professions (created by ConnectFunction)
>       in ConnectFunction (at HomePage.js:140)
>       in component (created by Context.Consumer)

also the following can be shown:

> Error: Given action "FETCH_PROFESSIONS", reducer "professions"
>   returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return
>   the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can
>   return null instead of undefined.
>       at combination (redux.js:463)
>       at p (:1:36402)
>       at v (:1:36684)
>       at :1:40069
>       at Object.dispatch (redux.js:212)
>       at e (:1:40553)
>       at index.js:11
>       at Object.dispatch (redux-saga-core.esm.js:1423)
>       at dispatch (:1:28545)
>       at Object.passToRedux (Professions.js:273)
>       at Professions.js:96

Answer (score 0):

It is shown when State change performed after component is unmounted.

Exp If you send an async API call and update state on its response, but before API respond you leave that component(change route or visit another page) then this warning will be shown. Because async API call will try to change state after response where is component is unmounted.

Solutions: Cancel all asynchronous call in componentWillUnmount() method.

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  //cancel API call etc which in progress and will update state.
}
```